# Convert a decimal array to string format in golang

Tags: string, go, decimal, converters

I want to convert a decimal array to text in string format in golang, is there any function in golang that supports this. Can you give me a sample code?
E.g :

```
97 98 99 
a b c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := []int{97, 98, 99}
    result := []string{}

    for _, element := range a {
        result = append(result, string(element))
    }

    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

[a b c]

https://go.dev/play/p/WUYIiIcHP16

Comment: Thank you very much, I am new to golang language, how about the opposite case.

Comment: Well, if you need to convert an array of runes to bytes then - https://go.dev/play/p/oVdMvmW6v6_b